# Заполнить строку одинаковыми символами

Tags: c++

Написать функцию, выполняющую действия, аналогичные действиям стандартной функции

```
char *strset(char *str, int c);
```

заполнение строки `str` заданным символом `c`.

Comment: Минусаторы, а за что минусуете-то?

Comment: видимо, за отсутствие навыка загуглить реализацию....

Answer (score 4):

Более оптимальный по производительности вариант - но обязательно нужен нулевой символ в строке (см. рефенс на strlen)

```
#include <cstring>

void SetStr(char* s, char c)
{
    std::memset(s, c, std::strlen(s));
}
```

Comment: Разве `strlen` есть в `cstring`? И вроде `memory.h` не хватает? Ща проверю.

Comment: А, нет, всё нормально: https://ideone.com/b7Qi5s

Answer (score 2):

Ничего тяжелого, думаю, что пояснения не нужны.

**strset**

```
 char* strset(char* str, int c)
 {
     char *t = str;
     while (*str!= 0)
     {
         *str= c;
         str++;

     }
     return t;
 }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100922/discussion-on-answer-by-blacit----).

Comment: см коммент к ответу Qwertiy

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал как-то так:

```
char *strset(char *s, char ch)
{
  for (char *p=s; *p; ++p)
    *p = ch;

  return s;
}
```

Comment: боль... memset куда эффективнее вплоть до O3

Comment: @Beeen007, хм.. strlen+memset. Да, возможно, вспоминая недавние измерения. Ответом опубликуй лучше.

Comment: просто добавь в свой ответ 2ой вариант

Comment: @Beeen007, зачем, если идея твоя?

Comment: Да и какая разница ) давай добавляй, я тем более с тел не люблю код форматить) а завтра уже забуду

Comment: @Beeen007, 4 пробела в начале строки поставить с телефона не любишь?)

Comment: Ну ладно, ладно смотри выше